# How to Query DB using .object in Django

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-templates

I have few categories. Say Electronics and Toy. and i have mutiple shops in a mall. A shop is saved with a foreign key(category). Now in the navigation bar.. i want to list stores based on their categories. Thanks in anticipation

```
models.py
class ShopCategories(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True,)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category

class NewShop(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(ShopCategories)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    tagline = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='Enter tagline here2')
    description = models.TextField(default='enter shop description')

    def __str__(self):
        return  self.name

views.py
def basefile(request):
    shop_cat = NewShop.objects.filter(category_id=1)
    shop_name = NewShop.objects.filter(name=shop_cat)
    return render_to_response('base.html', {'Shopname':shop_name, 'Shopcat':shop_cat})

base.html
    {% for category_id in Shopcat  %}
        <li><a href="#">{{ Shopname }}</a></l>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: We need you to specify more what your need. I mean, do you need a dropdown that depending on the categories choice it shows the shop list?

Comment: @BrianOcampo .. Exactly. A dropdown depending on the categories choice and shop list under the category

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Guys. I know this isn't the best method but i was able to fix it this way

models.py

```
class ShopCategories(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.category


class NewShop(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(ShopCategories)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    tagline = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='Enter tagline here2')
    description = models.TextField(default='enter shop description')
    def __str__(self):
        return  self.name
```

views.py

```
def basefile(request):
    cat1 = NewShop.objects.filter(category_id=1)
    cat2 = NewShop.objects.filter(category_id=2)
    cat3 = NewShop.objects.filter(category_id=3)
    cat4 = NewShop.objects.filter(category_id=4)
    shop_name1 = ShopCategories.objects.filter(id=1)
    shop_name2 = ShopCategories.objects.filter(id=2)
    shop_name3 = ShopCategories.objects.filter(id=3)
    shop_name4 = ShopCategories.objects.filter(id=4)

    return render_to_response('base.html', {'Shop_cat1':cat1, 'Shop_cat2':cat2, 'Shop_cat3':cat3,
                                        'Shop_cat4':cat4,'shop_name1':shop_name1, 'shop_name2':shop_name2,
                                        'shop_name3':shop_name3, 'shop_name4':shop_name4})
```

base.html

```
{% for shop_name1 in shop_name1 %}
    <li>
        <h3> {{ shop_name1 }}</h3>
    </li>
{% endfor %}

{% for Shop_cat1 in Shop_cat1  %}
    <li><a href="#">{{ Shop_cat1 }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get all store use below query.

```
shopcat = NewShop.objects.filter(category__category="category name")
```

base.html

```
{% for shop in shopcat  %}
    <li><a href="#">{{ shop.name }}</a></l>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try do this:

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...

    url(r'^get_shops_by_category/(?P<id_category>\d+)/$', views.get_shops_by_category, name = "get_shops_by_category"),
]
```

views.py

```
def basefile(request):
    categories = ShopCategories.objects.all()
    shop_name = NewShop.objects.filter(name=shop_cat)
    return render_to_response('base.html', {'Shopname':shop_name, 'categories': categories})

def get_shops_by_category(request, **kwargs):
    categories = ShopCategories.objects.all()
    current_category = ShopCategories.objects.get(id = kwargs['id_category']
    shops = NewShop.objects.filter(category = current_category)
    return render_to_response('base.html', {'shops': shops, 'categories': categories, 'current_category' current_category})
```

base.html

```
  ...
 <select>
     {% for category in categories  %}
         {% if current_category %}
             <option value="{{ category.id }}">{{ category.category }}</option>
         {% else %}
             <option value="{{ category.id }}" onclick="location.href = '{% url 'your_app:your_url' category.id %}'">{{ category.category }}</option>
     {% endfor %}
 </select>

 {% if shops %}
     <table>
         <thead>
             <tr>
                <th>Shop name</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
             </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
             {% for shop in shops %}
                 <tr>
                     <td>{{ shop.name }}</td>
                     <td><!-- Buttons or links, ect ... --></td>
                 </tr>
             {% endfor %}
         </tbody>
     </table>
 {% endif %}

 ...
```